# Tooltipster speed up for many active clickable elements

Tags: javascript, performance, tooltipster

I use Tooltipster library to provide tooltips for a huge number of words (about 8000) inside a single page. I do it by assigning Tooltipster to a class: $('.w').tooltipster({ ...

Therefore whenever a big enough page loads there's a lot of processing involved since every element of a class "w" has to be analyzed by the client to handle that tooltip. I wonder if there's a way to modify the code somehow to only do this for a specific element of a class "w" that is being clicked instead of looping through all of them at the beginning.

This is a very simple example from their page on which the slowdown is observed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.w').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'click',
        functionBefore: function(instance, helper) {
            instance.content('My new content');
        }
    });
});
```

Is it really necessary to invoke a loop there (via a Tooltipster or something else) to make every element of class "w" ready for a certain function/task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegation to create tooltips only when it's useful. It has its drawbacks in a few cases but it works well most of the time. You will find explanations on delegating for Tooltipster in the documentation: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#delegation

Comment: I didn't even think it was covered in the manual so missed that one. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - it works perfectly well now.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This works on Safari on a Mac, Windows Phone but curiously not on iOS devices - in iOS Safari debug mode the page loads without any errors but no tooltips appear whatsoever. Should I start another question or maybe you have some idea why that could be happening?

Comment: It's another issue, probably specific to your app, that you'll have to debug yourself. Check if there is not something that catches the click events to start with, and if the tooltips get initialized.

Comment: Yeah. Figured that one out: instead of "$('body').on('touchstart..." I was using "$('body').on('click..." which was ignored by iOS.